# How to tell if a [Swift] UITableViewCell is new or reused?

Tags: swift, uitableview

At the moment I have a label in my .xib and I am looking at its text to see if the cell is being used for the first time or not, which is working but I can see problems ahead with that method. Can anyone recommend something more robust please? Thank you.

Comment: Could you give some context as to why you need to know whether the cell is being reused?

Comment: you're right @Yasir, doesn't need checking, that's just an indication of something wrong elsewhere in the code. Thanks.